# Overriding window.close in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to override `window.close()` Method in JavaScript. Here is my code:

```
 (function () {
    var _close = window.close;                  
    window.close = function () {
        window.opener.alert("test");
        _close();                             
    };
})();
```

I am trying to bind this code to new window and execute the inner code when the new window is closed.
Is is possible to override `window.close` like this?

Comment: Have you tried it to see what happens?

Comment: yes, nothing happens when I close the new window.

Comment: did you look at window.unload?

Comment: If you could do this, it would be possible to create windows that could never be closed. Malware sites did this, so browsers don't allow it.

Comment: What flavor Window is this? A popup or the main? Maybe `.exitIntercept` could help?

Comment: event.preventDefault()?

Comment: Oh yes, please give me more popups when I try to close your advertising page that I didn't ask for in the first place.

Comment: @DevlshOne It is a popup window.

Comment: @fred02138 window.unload also doesn't works for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

You can use window.onbeforeunload event to call any function
However, alert,prompt,confirm boxes are not allowed.
you can return any string, to show any message.

```
//var _close = window.onbeforeunload;  
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
   // window.opener.alert("test");
   //_close();        
   return callBack();
};
function callBack()
{
    return "Testing";
}
```

If you suppose to close any other child window

You can try this

```
var k = window.open("url");
k.onbeforeunload = callBack;
```