# how to execute a function on close tab event?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms

I have function like below for detecting form closing like below
..
How can i do some task if user wishes to leave page

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {

        var y = e.pageY || e.clientY; //window.event.clientY; //

        if (y < 0) {
            return 'Window closed';
        }
        else {
            return 'Are You Sure Wants To Close Form?';
        }
    };
```

It just displays popup with text "Are You Sure Wants To Close Form?" ....but if user clicks yed i want to leave page how can do my task

Comment: Check this out

you can override it

http://stackoverflow.com/a/18395961/2704755

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

Its not possible by our usual way,just need some hack in this:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcCeg/7/)

```
var timeout;
$(window).on('beforeunload', function (){
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        alert('execute any function instead of me!!!!');
    }, 1000);
    return "exitinggggggggggggggggggggg";
});
```

Comment: dear VAGABOND i put alert in else code...but control is not going there when i press yes

Comment: wait 2 min ...updating my answer

Answer (score -1):

`window.onbeforeunload` is not cross-browser and there is no way to ensure that your code is going to run before a user leaves your page.

So, do not rely on `window.onbeforeunload`.