# Query database on beforeunload event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if its possible to send a query to the database on the beforeunload event.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload',function() {
    console.log('beforeunload called. run query');
});
```

If so, how would I do it? I need to run a query to insert dynamic values into the database.

Comment: Have you consider reading about Ajax call ?

Comment: This solution May work Try this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783535/jquery-beforeunload-when-closing-not-leaving-the-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, but beware that the `onbeforeunload` event is limited for certain browsers..

```
window.onbeforeunload = mySession;
function mySession(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/../../myPHP.php",
        async: false,
        type: "GET"
    });
    return "WhatEverMessageYouFeelLike";
}
```

and your PHP executing query from AJAX handling..

```
$delete = "DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE id=" .$_SESSION['mySessionVariable'];
// your query..
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to make it compatible with as many browsers as possible?

Comment: The `onbeforeunload` event is compatible for most commons browsers such as IE, Firefox & Chrome but I believe Safari and Opera are the exceptions in this case. **Update:** Opera version 15 and up now has support since they moved it to their WebKit engine.

Answer (score 0):

Use a jQuery AJAX call. Assuming you're POSTing your data, try this:

```
$.post(
    'your/url',
    {
        your : "Post Vars"
    },
    function(data) {
        // not sure if you'll need to do anything here actually.
    },
    'json' // or 'html', or whatever you want your return format to be
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks the best way to use post by jQuery is **$.post()** method.but u can also use **$.ajax**

Sample way to use is

**jQuery**

```
$.post( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
});
```

**jQuery Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: $. post is asynchronous (note the "asych:false" on $.ajax).  The browser won't sit around waiting for a response and server task may close before your code finishes.