# Show modal if page refreshed, but not if a link is followed

Tags: javascript, jquery

A visitor wants to leave the page (reload, refresh, close tab..etc.), and then a function is triggered prompting a modal "are you sure you want to leave?".

I want to allow them to leave the page without the modal prompt if they click on a link.

Here is a jsfiddle example- http://jsfiddle.net/vvj90z8h/3/

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="button">Proceed</a>      
<div class="price">$139.99</div>

// function
priceFunction = function (){
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        return 'Sure you want to leave?';
    }
};

// if price is 139.99, run function
var price = $(".price").text().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
if (price = 139.99){
    priceFunction();
}
```

If you refresh the page, the modal shows, which is okay.

I'm wanting to click the link and not have the modal show.

Comment: on what basis you want it to not prompt??

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to have "not prompting" be the default action and "prompting" be the explicit action?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783535/jquery-beforeunload-when-closing-not-leaving-the-page) question.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad the basis for it not to show was if that link was clicked

Comment: @David I had tried that route but the first condition was if the url contained "shoppingcart". I think that threw me off so I missed your suggested route in the first place. Thanks for the suggestion though, I might just try that anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unbind the `onbeforeunload` event listener on click :

```
$('#proceed').click(function(){ window.onbeforeunload = null; });
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/45jyxd2s/)

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag when they click or unbind the event

```
(function(){
    var pass = false;
    $(document.body).on("mousedown","a.button", function () {
        pass = true;
    });

    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        if(pass) return;
        return 'Sure you want to leave?';
    }

}());
```

or

```
(function(){

    $(document.body).on("mousedown","a.button", function () {
        $(window).off("beforeunload");    
    });

    $(window).on("beforeunload", function() {
        return 'Sure you want to leave?';
    });

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/jcqjj1u3/2/

```
// function
priceFunction = function (){
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            return 'Sure you want to leave?';
    }
};

// if price is 139.99, run function
var price = $(".price").text().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
if (price = 139.99){
    priceFunction();
}

var beforeUnloadFunction;

$('.button').click(function(){
    beforeUnloadFunction = window.onbeforeunload; // save the function for later just in case
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
    // following code is optional. Use it only if you need to do other stuff befre leaving
    event.preventDefault();
    // do other stuff before leaving if you'd like to
    location.href= $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot svassr! I saw Dystroys answer first but this also worked perfectly