# Firestore update document on beforeunload

Tags: asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, onbeforeunload

How can I update a document in Firestore on beforeunload?

```
    function sleep() {
      var start = new Date().getTime();
      while (new Date().getTime() < start + 3000);
    }

    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
      const ref = db.collection('users').doc(currentUser.uid);
      ref.update({
        profiles: true
      }).then(function() {
        console.log("Added!");
      });
      console.log("Blocking for 3 seconds...");
      sleep();
      console.log("Done!!");
    });
```

Seems like ref.update() is never called? Any idea why that's the case?

Comment: Are you able to see the subsequent logs: `console.log("Blocking for 3 seconds...");` and  `console.log("Done!!");`, meaning, are they executed?

Comment: I do see  console.log("Blocking for 3 seconds..."); but not the other one

Comment: can you share a sample document of your `users` collection?

Comment: You can think of it as a one field document: {profiles: true}

Comment: have you checked if `currentUser.uid` has the value you would expect to have?

Comment: Ya! It seems like async calls are just not allowed

Comment: yeah, apparently `onbeforeunload` does not handle async requests well, try changing it to async/await like this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64639231/12857703)