# Firestore Security Rules: check for value of list of map

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

A document looks like this

```
matches: [
{uid: ___ , ...},
{uid: ___ , ...},
]
```

How can I check if the uid of the user requesting this is in one of the uids in matches? I tried this but it did not work.

uid in `get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.matches.uid`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. The Security Rules language doesn't support `for` loops or things like `map`. You'll need to store your data differently. Either of these patterns could work:

```
// data structure
matches: ["uid1", "uid2", "uid3"]
// rules
allow: if uid in resource.data.matches;

// data structure
matches: {"uid1": true, "uid2": true}
// rules
allow: if resource.data.matches[uid] == true;
```

Alternatively if you know that the `matches` array can never be longer than, say, five elements, you could manually expand the statement:

```
allow: if resource.data.matches[0].uid == uid ||
          resource.data.matches[1].uid == uid ||
          // ...repeat three more times
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful! Curious if you have any suggesstions about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65895509/firestore-update-document-on-beforeunload