# Clear localStorage on tab/browser close but not on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, window

Is there a way to detect tab close event to clear the `localStorage`. I need `localStorage` to share data across tabs. `window.onbeforeunload` event works fine but it has 2 issues for me:

1. It also fires on page refresh which I dont want.
2. I don't need confirm box on tab close.

Like when window is closed the `sessionStorage` is cleared. At same time I can clear `localStorage` but don't know what event to bind to. I checked a few questions already available but none seems to address this issue there are workarounds by using flags for click on links and form submits but not a clean way to do it. Kindly suggest any solution for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capture the browser window close event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/how-to-capture-the-browser-window-close-event)

Comment: They're saying you can't really do that. [There are other ways of working around it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783535/jquery-beforeunload-when-closing-not-leaving-the-page) The point is, this question has been asked multiple times. Look through those questions and find what works for your situation.

Comment: Then read the other questions.

Comment: That's because you just copied and pasted some other code. That code handles if the user submits a form or clicks on a link, not refreshes the page. You need to actually understand the code you're using. Don't just blindly copy it.

Comment: hi mike. the above code was for your reference since you were saying about this being duplicate. I know that refresh is not being handled. Thats why i asked a new question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to find solution to this and thought of sharing. 
Since the window.onbeforeunload event fires on browser/tab close but on refresh as well(which i did not want) the thing was my localstorage was being processed at time of rfresh as well. Which I did not want. In order to overcome this I implemented 1 more event handler window.onload that fires only on refresh and not on tab/browser close where I would reset the localStorage as if nothing had happened. The code is:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    window.onunload = function () {
            window.localStorage.isMySessionActive = "false";
    }
    return undefined;
};

window.onload = function () {
            window.localStorage.isMySessionActive = "true";
};
```

I returned undefined in window.onbeforeunload as i did not want a confirm popup to appear on tab/browser close and refresh.

Comment: Vishal , tried same , onunload function also calling when the page is refreshed in chrome . It doesn't  fix issue

Comment: @JayanthSuvarna You seem to have not read the answer. It clearly mentions that this behavior is normal and how to resolve it.

Comment: Correct me if am not understood , window.onload that fires only on refresh and not on tab/browser close, My observation is  here  window.onunload will be called first , then it call 'window.onload' during the page refresh , once i clear the localStorage inside event 'window.onunload' how to retrieve back it in  window.onload ?

Comment: You set it back to what? You already cleared the localStorage on `onunload` event, which by the way, also clears `isMySessionActive` variable. There's nothing left to be set `onload`. Your solution can be used for clearing the localStorage only on refresh but not on close, in other words, if your question was the other way around.  @JayanthSuvarna is totally right in this one.

Comment: This is a completely wrong solution what he provided. it will not work this way.

Comment: what if the local storage we wanted to use was an dynamic variable instead of true. which we had set from another component itself.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the solution though it still clears the storage cache on page refresh. I tried to add debug steps by spitting out in console log to see if the window.onbeforeunload gets fired and esp. when.. can't see any entires though page refresh does clears the cache. My code is part of my app.js in my React app ...window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  console.log("winows event onbeforeunload event")
  window.onunload = function () {
         localStorage.removeItem("currentUser");
  }
  return undefined;
};

Answer (score 18):

I know that that is an old question, but I was just looking for a solution for this, but I couldn't find anything that works properly. Then I came up with a solution which is working fine for me.

What I did was to change the perspective, instead of clearing the local storage when the browser is closed I decided to clear it when it is opened. Users won't see the difference.

I just set a function that check the sessionStorage when the page is loaded, if it is empty the function gets the localStorage cleared; After that it sets a `register` to sessionStorage to ensure that the localStorage won't be emptied again just for having the page reloaded.

```
function clearStorage() {

    let session = sessionStorage.getItem('register');

    if (session == null) {
    
        localStorage.removeItem('remove');

    }
    sessionStorage.setItem('register', 1);
}
window.addEventListener('load', clearStorage);
```

Comment: For those who are want to clear local storage after the whole browser session is close (aka close the whole browser rather than the tab) can set a session cookie to check

Comment: The only caveat is that if users open some page in a new tab, the sessionStorage will be empty and the localStorage gets cleared (so if you refresh the tab in the original tab, the localStorage data is gone).

Answer (score 3):

Check if time between window.onbeforeunload event and window.onload event if it is less than 3 seconds keep the session live else remove the token.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {

window.localStorage.unloadTime = JSON.stringify(new Date());

};

window.onload = function () {

let loadTime = new Date();
let unloadTime = new Date(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.unloadTime));
let refreshTime = loadTime.getTime() - unloadTime.getTime();

if(refreshTime>3000)//3000 milliseconds
{
window.localStorage.removeItem("token");
}

};
```

Answer (score 3):

Use **cookie** to solve the issue, cookie value will automatically remove on browser close,
In my case I am using API with token, that stored in localStorage, so when browser close or shutdown it not logout the user, so what I done is

after login just set cookie with key 'loginstatus' and value 'loggedin'

```
document.cookie = "loginstatus=loggedin";
localStorage.setItem("token", token);
```

In the method checking user islogged by using localStorage value

```
isUserLoggedIn(){
   let session = localStorage.getItem('token');
   if (session == null) {
      return false;
   }else{
      return session
   }
}
```

Modified by removing localStorage token if cookie value doesn't exists

```
isUserLoggedIn(){
  // remove token if cookie not set
  if(this.getCookie("loginstatus") != 'loggedin'){
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
  }

  let session = localStorage.getItem('token');
  if (session == null) {
     return false;
  }else{
     return session
  }
}
```

and it worked !!!

Comment: What if the token expires?

Comment: pass token in header of API and validate token in middleware

Answer (score 1):

PS: Indonesian is my mother language, so I'm sorry if I'm bad at explaining in English.

If you want to keep your last action on tab refresh, but want to clear your last action on tab close, then I really recommend you to use sessionStorage instead of localStorage. Because as I know, if you use localStorage, then your last action will be cleared automatically when you clear your browser history, so that means if you want to clear your last action manually (e.g. you want it to be cleared on tab close), then you have to use localStorage.removeItem('').
BUT... if you use sessionStorage, then your last action will be cleared automatically when you close the tab (even though you never close your browser). And that means your last action will be kept continuously as long as you don't close the tab that loads the url/the page. So if you close that tab (but you don't close your browser) & just load the url/the page again in new tab, then sessionStorage will be in its initial value/state, because your last action that was in sessionStorage was removed automatically when you close the tab.

And if you want an example, here is my full code that I achieve from googling for almost a week. Btw I checked the result using the RUN CODE SNIPPET here, so even though it seems like there's something wrong, just try to save my html file here & open it in your browser. Because I use Visual Studio Code to edit & run the html file, and even if I open that file in Chrome, it works fine. And btw, you can change alert('') to console.log('') if you want your page to be more convenient for user.

```js
function changeVisibility() {
    document.getElementById("imgbox2").style.visibility="visible";
    images = document.getElementById("imgbox2").style.visibility;
    sessionStorage.setItem('imagesVis', images);
    alert("Pt.1 CLICKED; images BECOME VISIBLE");
  }
  // When the user clicks on the button, toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  }
  // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
      var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
      }
    }
  }
  window.onload = function() {
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('imagesVis')) {
      document.getElementById("imgbox2").style.visibility="visible";
      alert("Pt.1 HAS BEEN CLICKED before; images STAY VISIBLE");
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("imgbox2").style.visibility="hidden";
      alert("Pt.1 NEVER CLICKED before; images STAY HIDDEN");
    }
  }
```

```css
.imgbox {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
}
button {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: grey;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: grey;
  border: 4px outset darkgrey;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
}
/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  color: black;
  border-style: groove;
}
/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2em; /* set the position of the dropdown button and its contents */
}
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  height: 9.5em;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  color: black; font-weight: bold;
}
/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Select Part</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <button onclick="changeVisibility()"><a href="#">Pt.1</a></button>
      <a href="#">Pt.2</a>
      <a href="#">Pt.3</a>
      <a href="#">Pt.4</a>
      <a href="#">Pt.5</a>
      <a href="#">Pt.10</a>
      <a href="#">Pt.50</a>
      <a href="#">Pt.100</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgbox" id="imgbox2">
    <div style="background-color: #484444; max-height: 15em; overflow: auto; width: max-content; margin: auto;">
        <a style="display: flex; padding: 0; text-align: center;"><img border="0" data-original-height="5469" data-original-width="575" src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/naturerules1/images/7/7b/White-persian-cats-picture-id637190306.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20210426035333"></a>
        <a style="display: flex; padding: 0; text-align: center;"><img border="0" data-original-height="5458" data-original-width="576" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/03/16/07/45/turkish-angora-7071832_1280.jpg"></a>
        <a style="display: flex; padding: 0; text-align: center;"><img border="0" data-original-height="5466" data-original-width="575" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612356700139-ba3b20f5f468?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8bHlueHxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&w=1000&q=80"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SessionStorage` instead. It gets cleared off whenever the tab is closed.

Comment: I need localStorage to share data across tabs.

Comment: It will not work as expected as its specific to tabs

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is quite old, but maybe someone still needs it.

This solution is not pretty, but it works quite well:

```js
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload')
  setToSession(): void {
    const token = this.authenticationService.currentTokenValue;
    sessionStorage.setItem('tempToken', JSON.stringify(token));
  }

  @HostListener('window:load')
  clearLocalStorage(): void {
    const session = sessionStorage.getItem('tempToken');
    const user = this.authenticationService.currentTokenValue.user;
    const loginMode = user.loginMode;
    console.log(loginMode);
    if (!loginMode && session == null) {
      console.log('TOKEN REMOVED');
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      window.location.reload();
    }
  }
```

A temporary token is stored in the sessionStorage when closing/reloading, which is queried when reloading. Only if the token is there and the loginMode is false, the storage is deleted.