# Need to clear local storage on browser tab closed not on refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

Need to clear local storage on browser tab closed not on refresh.  I tried

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    localStorage.clear();
};
```

it clears the localstorage when browser refresh happens.  I want to force the user to login when the user close browser tab.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943220/how-to-delete-a-localstorage-item-when-the-browser-window-tab-is-closed

Comment: Try this `localStorage.$reset();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a localStorage item when the browser window/tab is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943220/how-to-delete-a-localstorage-item-when-the-browser-window-tab-is-closed)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128931/clear-localstorage-on-tab-browser-close-but-not-on-refresh

Answer (score 4):

Refreshing and closing a tab/window is the same event as far as the browsers are concerned.

Best would be to use `session storage` rather than `local storage` as session would be active until the tab/window is closed and not refreshed and you aren't saving persistent data.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568977/identifying-between-refresh-and-close-browser-actions)

Answer (score -4):

Use this code.

```
window.onload = window.localStorage.clear();
```