# How to clean localeStorage only after closing the browser (VueJs)?

Tags: vue.js, events, vuejs2, vue-component

The question was: "How to clean localeStorage only after closing the browser (not closing the browser tab and reloading the page). And this must be implemented in the Vue component.
Found the following solution ([Clear localStorage on tab/browser close but not on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128931/clear-localstorage-on-tab-browser-close-but-not-on-refresh)):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    window.onunload = function () {
            window.localStorage.isMySessionActive = "false";
    }
    return undefined;
};

window.onload = function () {
            window.localStorage.isMySessionActive = "true";
};
```

But I do not understand how to properly and where to call these listeners.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply register your listeners in your `main.js` file or in your `App.vue` file

`main.js`

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  beforeMount() {
    window.addEventListener("load", this.onLoad);
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.onUnload);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener("load", this.onLoad);
    window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", this.onUnload);
  },
  methods: {
    onLoad(event) {
      window.localStorage.setItem("isMySessionActive", true);
    },
    onUnload(event) {
      window.localStorage.setItem("isMySessionActive", false);
    }
  },
  render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

`App.vue`

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" width="25%">
    <HelloWorld msg="Hello World!"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  beforeMount() {
    window.addEventListener("load", this.onLoad);
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.onUnload);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener("load", this.onLoad);
    window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", this.onUnload);
  },
  methods: {
    onLoad(event) {
      window.localStorage.setItem("isMySessionActive", true);
    },
    onUnload(event) {
      window.localStorage.setItem("isMySessionActive", false);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I will add soon whether it works or not)

Comment: @KolisbikBoh it works or not ?

Comment: @maha-oueghlani it should be