# Redirect on refresh with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to detect when  the user refresh the page to redirect using JQuery ,what is wrong in this code?
but nothing that I try works

```
<?php
  include 'instagram.php';
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <?php
      $inst = new Instagram($_GET['code']);
     ?>

     <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
              crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script>
      $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
            alert("tryng to refresh");
        });
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery beforeunload when closing (not leaving) the page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783535/jquery-beforeunload-when-closing-not-leaving-the-page)

Comment: $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    // your logic here
}); use this

Comment: inside `$(document).ready`??

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. Chrome is blocking the alert.

Notice how the **console.log** runs with no problems.

This is the code I tested:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
  alert("tryng to refresh");
  console.log('leaving page');
  return '';
});
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: I'm using firefox and nothing is shown in the console