# call my logout function when browser/tab is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my application **I have to forcefully log out user when they close tab or browser**.I have logout function and I want to call it when user closes tab/browser.I have tried this piece of code but it didn't worked for me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(window).bind("beforeunload", function () {
                fnLogOut();
            })
        });
        function fnLogOut() { alert('browser closing'); }
 </script>
```

Any help?

Comment: Are you doing an ajax request inside `fnLogOut`? If so, you need to specify `async:false`, otherwise the browser will kill the thread before the ajax is sent.

Comment: browser tab is closed , where were you do your function ?

Comment: You need to launch a popup which will do the logout and close itself. `onbeforeunload` is not guaranteed to keep the browser open till the logout is completed.

Comment: @gurvinder372 popup is not being launched on close of tab. i have tried above code

Comment: Already we have post for this purpose: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783535/jquery-beforeunload-when-closing-not-leaving-the-page

Comment: Sometimes my browser crashes/freezes, and I kill the task in the taskmanager. What about that? `I have to forcefully log out user when they close tab or browser` Basically, why? Why can't you log them out in the backend if they are idle for a while?