# Prevent page from exiting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've made a function to give a warning when a user navigates away when a certain form field is populated:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
    var unsaved = "Are you sure you want to exit?";
    var text = $('.article_div textarea').val();
    if (text.length > 0){
        event.returnValue = unsaved;
        return unsaved;
    }
});
```

This actually works perfectly. However, I looked up [returnValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/returnValue) and it is recommended to not use it. I have tried alternatives including removing `event.returnValue = unsaved;` and just using `return unsaved`. However, that also doesn't work - it still navigates away from the page.

Any ideas as to what I can do to make it work?

Comment: "Any idea what I can do?"  You cite one source; have you done more research?

Comment: You can't prevent that user leaves the page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery, *event.returnValue* can be omitted. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783535/jquery-beforeunload-when-closing-not-leaving-the-page).

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(event) {
 var unsaved = "Are you sure you want to exit?";
    var text = 'Test Text @@@';
    //var text = $('.article_div textarea').val();
    if (text.length > 0){
            return unsaved;
    }
});
```

See [example here](https://jsfiddle.net/t9nfxjmv/).

Comment: Thankyou - changing `window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {` to `$(window).on('beforeunload', function(event) {` works.