# Detect Window Close with JQuery or Javascript AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get an Update about this topic.

I find many posts here on how to use unload() and onbeforeunload events, but there are not working for me. I try putting inside and outside `$(document).ready(function(){}` but it is not resulting. I will show the post (5 years ago) where it lead me to create a new one. How should we use? Thank you!

[jquery beforeunload when closing (not leaving) the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18783535/jquery-beforeunload-when-closing-not-leaving-the-page)

I try using without on, with onbeforeunload etc.

Does not run the code inside the event. :S

This is the code:

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function () {
    return 'hi';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Cierre_unload.php',
        success: function () {

        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Share your code to determine which part is not working

Comment: add an event listener to the window object. window.addEventListener("unload", function() { //do stuff })

Comment: The page is unloading. Any async requests will be dropped. You *might* be able to use a synchronous request but even that may be washed away by the browser.

Comment: - GiffCo , its not working :S (I use Chrome) Can't figure it out...

Comment: You can't do this.  The older question you linked to is outdated.  `onbeforeunload`  and window unload handlers can really only be used to show a confirm dialog at this point.

Comment: Only works for an alert message, then?

Comment: Thank you Niet the Dark Absol for clarifying :)

Comment: BANG! WORK IT! I CLOSE THE WINDOW AND DID THE AJAX REQUEST! I CHECK IT IN MYSQL UPDATE! :) The event triggers whenever the user leaves the page :)

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include the answer (or the word "SOLVED" in the title).  You can post an answer on your own question, if you've found a solution.  (Are you sure you have?  Browsers explicitly prevent async requests in unload handlers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945932/window-onbeforeunload-ajax-request-in-chrome)

Comment: Hi Daniel Beck! It worked the AJAX request, I check it in MySQL. Probably worked with beforeunload event but haven't try it with unload. Okay! I new in here when it comes to posting. Thanks for the next time! :) Gonna check the post now...

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I probably made a mistake but I sort it out! :) The AJAX request is working whenever the user leaves the page :)

**IMPORTANT**

To accomplish this task it should be use beforeunload event, which run just before leaving the page (unloading the page). For example, I close the window and the AJAX request was made, recorded the progress with MySQL.

Hope you find it useful :)

*Open to a debate, whether it's a good practice to use :)*